# ActorPublisher as Comet Event Source in Play Application

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, comet

I'm trying to write an Actor which connects to an Amazon Kinesis stream and then relays any messages received via Comet to a Web UI. I'm using Source.actorPublisher for this and using the json method with Comet in Play described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaComet). I got the events working just fine using Source.tick(), but when I tried using an ActorPublisher, the Actor never seems to be sent any `Request` messages as expected. How are requests for data usually sent down an Akka flow? I'm using v2.5 of the Play Framework.

My controller code:

```
def subDeviceSeen(id: Id): Action[AnyContent] = Action {
  val deviceSeenSource: Source[DeviceSeenMessage, ActorRef] = Source.actorPublisher(DeviceSeenEventActor.props)
  Ok.chunked(deviceSeenSource
    .filter(m => m.id == id)
      .map(Json.toJson(_))
        via Comet.json("parent.deviceSeen")).as(ContentTypes.JSON)
}
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong in the above? Here is my Actor code:

```
object DeviceSeenEventActor {
  def props: Props = Props[DeviceSeenEventActor]
}

class DeviceSeenEventActor extends ActorPublisher[DeviceSeenMessage] {

implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()(context)

val log = Logging(context.system, this)

def receive: Receive = {
  case Request => log.debug("Received request message")
                  initKinesis()
                  context.become(run)
  case Cancel => context.stop(self)
}

def run: Receive = {
  case vsm:DeviceSeenMessage => onNext(vsm)
                                 log.debug("Received request message")
                                 onCompleteThenStop() //we are currently only interested in one message
  case _:Any                  => log.warning("Unknown message received by event Actor")
}

private def initKinesis() = {
  //init kinesis, a worker is created and given a reference to this Actor.
  //The reference is used to send messages to the actor.
}
```

}

The 'Received request message' log line is never displayed. Am I missing some implicit? There are no warnings or anything else obvious displayed in the play console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was pattern matching on `case Request => ...` instead of `case Request() => ...`. Since I didn't have a default case in my `receive()` method, the message was simply dropped by the Actor.